# Why are generics called generics?

Tags: generics, language-agnostic, semantics

At the risk of becoming the village idiot, can someone explain to me why generics are called generics?  I understand their usage and benefits, but if the [definition of generic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/generic) is "general" and generic collections are type safe, then why isn't this a misnomer?

For example, an ArrayList can hold anything that's an object:

```
ArrayList myObjects = new ArrayList();
myObjects.Add("one");
myObjects.Add(1);
```

while a generic collection of type string can only hold strings:

```
var myStrings = new List<string>();
myStrings.Add("one");
myStrings.Add("1");
```

I'm just not clear on why it's called "generic".  If the answer is "...which make it possible to design classes and methods that defer the specification of one or more types until the class or method is declared and instantiated by client code." from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t(VS.80).aspx), then I suppose that makes sense.  Perhaps I'm having this mental lapse because I only began programming after Java introduced generics, so I don't recall a time before them.  But still...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"Generic" is talking about the implementation.  You write a single "Generic" list implementation that works with any type, instead of having to write specific implementations for each type you want to use.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense.  So the implementation is generic, until you instantiate it, at which point it becomes a "specific" generic? :)

Comment: Or rather, you're taking a specific instance of the generic :P

Comment: Don't use instance like that, "instance" already means something,

Comment: A "specific generic" is, in fact, often known as "specialization", though it depends on the language. In .NET, for example, we speak of "open generic types" (those that still have unfilled type parameters) and "closed generic types" (those that don't).

Answer (score 15):

I think the right answer to questions like this is almost always "historical reasons, mostly". Generics could just as well have been called "schemes" or "classes" or "type families" or "genera" or "type functions" or "statics" or "Greek types" or any of a million other things. Long ago someone decided to use the word "generic", and it stuck.

"Generic" in the Java sense dates back at least to the mid-1970s. The U.S. Department of Defense was honing a requirements document for its new programming language (what would become ADA). An early draft (["Woodenman"](http://www.iment.com/maida/computer/requirements/woodenman.htm#sb.8), August 1975) says:

> Compile time parameters are needed in extensible languages to permit specification of generic procedures and data structures such as stacks, and queues without repeating the definition for each element type.

This is the only use of "generic" in the document. It's not clear to me how it was intended. But by July 1977 (["Tinman"](http://www.iment.com/maida/computer/requirements/ironman.htm#s12.)) there was a whole paragraph on generics, and the term had clearly come to mean something specific:

> 12D.  GENERIC DEFINITIONS
>
> It shall be possible to define functions, procedures, and types with parameters that are instantiated during translation at each call. Such parameters may be any defined identifier (including those for variables, functions, or types), an expression, or a statement. These parameters, like all other parameters, shall be evaluated in the context of the call.

By June 1978 (["Steelman"](http://www.iment.com/maida/computer/steel/steelman.htm)) it was established jargon; there were other uses of the term "generic" in other sections of the document, clearly referring to this feature. In the finished language, `generic` was a reserved word.

---

The earliest plausibly related use of "generic" I found in academia was in Robin Milner's ["A theory of type polymorphism in programming"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.67.5276) (1978) (and he feels compelled to explain what he means by "generic", so it can't have been in common use in academia at that time):

> So this is the generic type of *map*, that is, to any occurrence of *map* within the scope of this declaration must be assigned some substitution instance of this type.

"Generic type variable" became CS jargon.

Comment: Great history on generics.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
bool Equals(int x, int y)
```

The above method can only compare integers, so we can say that it is *specialized* for comparing integers.

```
bool Equals<T>(T x, T y);
```

The above method can compare values of any type, so we can say that it isn't *specialized* for any particular type - it's *generic*.

Comment: What would you put in the body of the method?

Answer (score 1):

I dont want to get into the semantics of language (english, not java), and at the risk of answering you with a tautology; a generic method is called generic because, as you said, its can be used the the general sense, it doesnt have a specific type, it can be used generally

Comment: This makes some sense to me ... at a framework level, one has `List<T>`it is generic. It becomes specific in implementation,  `List<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, take this with a grain of salt, because I'm ***totally*** guessing, but I wonder whether it might be a bastardization of "Generative Types".

Conceptually, when you specialize a List into a List< String >, it generates a new type. At least, that's the way it works in C++ templates and in C# generics.

In Java, since the parameterizations are discarded by the compiler using type erasure, it actually ***doesn't*** generate a new specialized type, so who knows?

I suppose you could say that Java implements a genericized version of generative types :)

---

ON EDIT:

Here's another point of view...

The type List< String > is not what they're talking about when they refer to a "generic" type. I think the terminology is actually referring to the List< T > type, which is how the type exists in its generic form. List< String > is a specialization of the generic List< T >.

Answer (score 0):

If they called it "type parameter(s)" people would confuse it with parameters of type Type.

Also, ArrayList isn't "generic".  It ONLY works with types of object.  If you ask it for something, it will give you an object reference.  That's a very specific behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I was researching that and came across this post in my Googling, http://bytes.com/forum/thread244697.html at which time I realized that Jon Skeet is in all places at all times.

Answer (score 0):

A class which takes objects is NOT generic, it is very specifically taking a *type* which is itself a generic type.  A generic class, on the other hand, can be used with any specific type.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating "Generic" code that will be capable of operating on any type (within constraints you specify) in the same way...

a good example you are familiar with is the Add operator is just about any language... it can "Add" integers, floats, doubles, decimals, binarys, hexadecimals, regardless of whether they are signed, unsogned, how many bits they are, etc...

Answer (score -1):

I am not a "native" English Speaker, so I could be wrong but the point of the "Generics" is that the Define Generics types, isn't it?