# why did generic collection get that name when it is specific to perticular obect

Tags: java

```
List <Example> list =new ArrayList<Example>();
```

Why is the above list called generic list when it is specific to Example object only . I'm really confused on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that perspective, it does sound like a contradiction. My view is that the focus was on making the collection type safe to any (generic) object. Speaking in your terms and in the scope of your example, you can make a list specific to any (generic) object.

You have an older post discussing it in more details [Why are generics called generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309206/why-are-generics-called-generics).

By the way if you find it to be an exact duplicate you can mark you question so.

Comment: Yes my question is exactly the same as one you mentioned. Thanks a lot ..I'm clear now

Answer (score 0):

Making a small change to your code

List  list =new

ArrayList();

Now we can' t we call them generics . This arraylist accepts only classes that are subtypes of class Example

Generics are basically used to abstract over data types.  In the above example you can write a single list implementation that will work across a plethora of different types